# ListView should have the number of items as the number given in edittext in android studio

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

i have a edittext box and a button.if I give a number for ex. 25 in edit text and when I click the button, it should take me to another activity which has listview in it and automatically 25 list items should be added in that listview.thanks for responce

Comment: What's is the actual issue ? you can't create a listview with n items or can't fetch number from edittext

Comment: Restrict your adapter? Supply only the first `20` elements with the Arraylist?

Comment: Simply pass the editText value (let say n) to second activity . And in second Activity , add same nth number of objects in Adapter and set it to listView.

Answer (score 0):

```
                Try following code. This may help you:
In FirstActivity(onClick event of button):
                String num=textView.getText().toString();
                Intent i=new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,NextActivity.this);
                i.putExtra("intVariableName", num);
                startActivity(i);

                In NextActivity:
                Intent mIntent = getIntent();
                int count = mIntent.getIntExtra("intVariableName", 0);
        Now you have number to insert number of items in listView. Add count number of items in ListView.
```